# ionic cordova video capture: video composition must have a positive renderSize'

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to integrate this video editor into an ionic/cordova app: https://github.com/imgly/vesdk-cordova

It actually works really well using a test mp4 video built into the ionic assets, but what i need is to record a video with the device camera and load it in.

So with a saved test.mp4 this works:

```
VESDK.openEditor(
                (args: VideoEditorResult) => {
                  console.log("SUCCESS ARGS",args)
                },
                (error:any) => {
                  console.log("FAIL ERROR",error)
                },
                VESDK.resolveStaticResource('www/assets/test.mp4')
                
              );
```

However if i try to load in the media from the camera:

```
VESDK.resolveStaticResource(media[0].fullPath)
```

Xcode shows this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVPlayerItem
> setVideoComposition:] video composition must have a positive
> renderSize'

This seems like something is wrong when it records the video. It's iPhone 11 i am testing on.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that using the `VESDK.resolveStaticResource` function should only be used for loading in static resources that you are shipping inside your application bundle (your `www/assets` folder). This said, please pass in a valid URI without wrapping it inside this function.